# 3 dimensional python battleship game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, homework, battleship

I have an assignment in a python course. We were instructed to make a 3D Battleships game for 2 players on the same computer. I've written a code that works, according to the assignment instructions, but I think it looks a little messy. I'm a beginner. Any suggestions to make the code simpler and tidier?

```
import numpy as np
from enum import Enum


class Input(Enum):
    MISS = 'Miss'
    HIT = 'Hit'
    KILL = 'Kill'
    END = 'End'

class Pieces:
    """ all of the game pieces base class """
    def __init__(self, item_id: int):
        self.item_id = item_id
        self.outline = np.array([0])
        self.locs = None

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self.outline.shape

    @property
    def filled_outline(self):
        return self.outline * self.item_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}{self.item_id}"


class General(Pieces):
    """A number is submitted as input for compatibility, which is the game's determining piece"""
    def __init__(self, item_id: int):
        super().__init__(item_id)
        self.outline = np.array([[1]], dtype=np.int16)
        self.airplane = np.random.randint(3)

    def hit(self, coord):
        return Input.END


class Jet(Pieces):
    """ Class for the airplane vessels """
    def __init__(self, item_id: int):
        super().__init__(item_id)
        self.outline = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.int16)
        self.airplane = 2  # air

    def hit(self, coord):
        return Input.KILL


class Destroyer(Pieces):
    """ class for ships 'Destroyers'"""
    def __init__(self, item_id: int):
        super().__init__(item_id)
        self.outline = np.array([[1], [1], [1], [1]], dtype=np.int16)
        self.airplane = 1  # Sea-level

    def hit(self, cord: tuple):
        cord = list(cord)
        try:
            self.locs.remove(cord)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"This cordination is not found or already targeted -{cord}")
            return Input.MISS
        else:
            if len(self.locs) == 0:
                return Input.KILL
            else:
                return Input.HIT


class Submarine(Pieces):
    """ a Submarine vessel """
    def __init__(self, item_id: int):
        super().__init__(item_id)
        self.outline = np.array([[1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.int16)
        self.airplane = 0 

    def hit(self, coord):
        return Input.KILL


class GamePieces(Enum):
    """ the pieces type in the game"""
    General = General
    JETS = Jet
    DESTROYERS = Destroyer
    SUBMARINES = Submarine


class gameBoard(np.ndarray):
    """
    A three dimensional board that holds the pieces.
    """
    def __new__(subtype, shape: tuple=(10, 10, 3), dtype: np.dtype=np.object, *,
                pieces: list):
        if len(shape) != 3:
            return ValueError(f"Shape received was {shape}, but it must have exactly 3 items.")

        obj = super(gameBoard, subtype).__new__(subtype, shape, dtype)
        obj.pieces = pieces
        obj[:] = 0
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        """ A unique method which is run after initialization """
        if obj is None: return
        default_pieces = [piece.value(item_id) for item_id, piece in enumerate(GamePieces)]
        self.pieces = getattr(obj, 'pieces', default_pieces)

    def pieces_places(self):
        """
        Verifies that the piece was not put outside the board's bounds and that the cells were empty.
        """
        for piece in self.pieces:
            placed = False
            trial = 0
            while not placed and trial < 50:
                row_idx = np.random.choice(self.shape[0])
                col_idx = np.random.choice(self.shape[1])
                cur_slice = (slice(row_idx, row_idx + piece.shape[0]),
                             slice(col_idx, col_idx + piece.shape[1]),
                             slice(piece.airplane, piece.airplane + 1))
                try:
                    cur_subboard = self[cur_slice].copy()
                    assert cur_subboard.shape[:2] == piece.shape
                    assert np.all(cur_subboard == 0) 
                    placed = True
                except (IndexError, AssertionError):
                    pass
                finally:
                    trial += 1

            if trial >= 50:
                raise UserWarning("Board is too small for all pieces.")

            self[cur_slice] += np.atleast_3d(piece.filled_outline)
            piece.locs = np.argwhere(self == piece.item_id).tolist()
            self[self == piece.item_id] = piece

    def check_if_hit(self, coord: tuple) -> Input:
        """
        Receive a 3D coordinate of the location that was targeted.
        Then check the board which piece is there and return the Input.
        :param coord: Tuple of 3 coordinates
        :return: Input
        """
        cell = self[coord]
        if cell != 0:
            sig = cell.hit(coord)
            if sig is Input.KILL:
                self.pieces.remove(cell)
                if len(self.pieces) == 1:
                    sig = Input.END
        else:
            sig = Input.MISS
        return sig


class SubmarinesGame:
    """
    Play a Submarines game for two players. Run it with the start() method.
    Supply a tuple defining the 3D board size, and adictionary of unit names (from GamePieces) and values,
    corresponding to the number of units you wish to have of that size.
    At each turn you're prompted to enter a length-3 tuple with the coordinate you're targeting.
    You'll be notified if you missed, hit or killed a unit. You can also write "show" to show the board,
    and "quit" to stop the game.
    """

    def __init__(self, board_shape: tuple=(10, 10, 3), pieces: dict=None):
        self.board_shape = board_shape
        self.pieces = pieces
        self.piece_list_1 = []
        self.piece_list_2 = []

        self.__validate_input()
        self.__generate_pieces_list()

        self.board1 = gameBoard(self.board_shape, pieces=self.piece_list_1)
        self.board2 = gameBoard(self.board_shape, pieces=self.piece_list_2)

        self.players = ("Player 1", "Player 2")
        self.boards = (self.board2, self.board1)
        self.move = 0

    def __validate_input(self):
        assert len(self.board_shape) == 3
        assert self.board_shape[2] == 3  # only 3D inputs
        assert self.board_shape[0] >= 4 and self.board_shape[1] >= 4
        if self.pieces is not None:
            for piece, val in self.pieces.items():
                assert piece in GamePieces
                assert isinstance(val, int)
                assert val >= 0 and val <= 50
            assert GamePieces.General in self.pieces
            assert self.pieces[GamePieces.General] == 1

    def __generate_pieces_list(self):
        """ Populate the list of pieces """
        if self.pieces is not None:
            item_id = 1
            for piece, num in self.pieces.items():
                for cur_instance in range(num):
                    self.piece_list_1.append(piece.value(item_id))
                    self.piece_list_2.append(piece.value(item_id))
                    item_id += 1

    def __assert_coor_in_board(self, coord):
        coor_list = []
        for char in coord:
            if char.isdigit():
                coor_list.append(int(char))
        coord = tuple(coor_list)
        try:
            assert len(coord) == 3
            assert coord[0] < self.board1.shape[0] \
                and coord[1] < self.board1.shape[1] \
                and coord[2] < self.board1.shape[2]
        except AssertionError:
            print(f"Coordinate {coord} is located outside the board. Board shape is {self.board1.shape}.")
            return False
        else:
            return coord

    def __parse_input(self):
        """ Helper function to parse the input from the user """
        coor = input(f"{self.players[self.move % 2]} this is your turn. type you target! for example: (1,1,1) ")
        if coor == 'quit':
            raise SystemExit("Exiting")
        if coor == 'show':
            board = self.boards[(self.move-1) % 2]
            print("Under-water:\n", board[..., 0])
            print("Sea-level:\n", board[..., 1])
            print("Air:\n", board[..., 2])
            return False
        coor = self.__assert_coor_in_board(coor)
        return coor

    def start(self):
        """ Battleships game """

        print("This is a game of Battleships\n")
        print(f"The board dimensions are {self.board1.shape} and the pieces are assigned randomly.")
        print("You can type 'show' to show your board, and 'quit' to exit the game.")
        for board in self.boards:
            board.pieces_places()

        ret_Input = 0

        while ret_Input !=  Input.END:
            coor = False
            while not coor:
                coor = self.__parse_input()

            ret_Input = self.boards[self.move % 2].check_if_hit(coor)
            print(ret_Input)
            self.move += 1

        print(f"The game is over! The winner is {self.players[(self.move - 1) % 2]}.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pieces = {GamePieces.General: 1,
              GamePieces.JETS: 1,
              GamePieces.DESTROYERS: 1,
              GamePieces.SUBMARINES: 1}
    subgame = SubmarinesGame(board_shape=(6, 6, 3), pieces=pieces)
    subgame.start()
```

Comment: Please include the assignment instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with this code is readability. The actual program looks well-structured (good functions, reasonable use of classes, use of appropriate libraries, etc).

There are a large number of very small things to fix.

We'll start with naming, the biggest problem. I've put a complete list of suggested renames, with a very short explanation of why. The reasons are to:

- **consistency**: Remove inconsistency within your program (Don't use `coor`, `cord` and `coord`. Pick one.)
- **convention**: Follow common programmer convention (use the singular class name `Piece`, not `Pieces`). Read PEP8, mentioned below, to learn common Python conventions.
- **english**: Learn and write correct English (`pieces_places` should be `place_pieces`).
- **clarity**: Think about clear names (`ret_Input` becomes `guess_outcome`). This is the hardest but most important.

In rough order of appearance, rename:

- `Input` to `GuessOutcome` (clarity)
- `Input.END` to GuessOutcome.END_GAME` (clarity)
- `Pieces` to `Piece` (convention--singular classes)
- `GamePieces.General` to `GamePieces.GENERAL` (consistency)
- `gameBoard` to `GameBoard` (convention)
- `pieces_places` to `place_pieces` (english)
- `check_if_hit` to `is_hit` (convention)
- `SubmarinesGame.__validate_input` to `SubmarinesGame._validate` (convention--input is always user input)
- `SubmarinesGame._generate_pieces_list` to `SubmarinesGame._populate_unplaced_pieces` (clarity--prefer action verbs)
- `SubmarinesGame.__assert_coor_in_board` to `SubmarinesGame._assert_coordinate_on_board` (consistency and english)
- `SubmarinesGames.__parse_input` to `SubmarinesGames._get_guess` (clarity and convention)
- Piece: `piece.locs` to `piece.squares_occupied` (clarity and convention--avoid abbreviations in python)
- Piece: `piece.outline` to ?? (clarity, not sure what this is)
- Piece: `piece.airplane` to piece.height (clarity and maybe english)
- Destroyer: `cord` to `coordinate` (consistency, english, and convention--avoid abbreviations in python)
- GameBoard.check_if_hit: `coord` to `coordinate` (consistency and convention)
- SubmarinesGame: `self.piece_list_1` and `self.piece_list_2` to `self.players[0].pieces` and `self.players[1].pieces` (clarity and convention--prefer array variables to multiple variables)
- SubmarinesGame: `self.board1` and `self.board2` to `self.players[0].board` and `self.players[1].board` (clarity and convention)
- SubmarinesGame: `self.move` to `self.turn_number` (clarity)
- SubmarinesGame: `self.pieces` to `SUBMARINES_PIECES` (convention--should be a constant, and clarity that it's a map from type of piece to number of pieces)
- SubmarinesGame.__generate_pieces_list: `cur_instance` to `_` (convention--unused loop variables get a dummy name `_` in python to indicate they're not used)
- SubmarinesGame.__assert_coor_in_board: `coord` to `unparsed_coordinate` / the second variable called `coord` to `parsed_coordinate` (consistency, clarity, convention of not re-using variable names)
- SubmarinesGame.__assert_coor_in_board: `coor_list` to `coordinate_list` (consistency)
- SubmarinesGame.start: `coor` to `coordinate` (consistency)
- SubmarinesGame.start: `ret_Input` to `guess_outcome` (clarity)

The way you've split up functions is pretty good.

Other things to improve, in no particular order:

- Read, understand, and follow [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). This is the standard Python style guide.
- Consistently use type hints. Add a type for a single 3-D coordinate
- `print` in only one place, not across several functions. Printing in the main game loop (`start`) would be a good single place here.
- This code is hard to read without knowing numpy. A few comments would be helpful.
- Don't have GameBoard inherit from np.ndarray, as mentioned in Kache's review.
- Write docstrings. Yours look copied. Your functions should each do one clear thing, and return something clear. This is what the docstring should explain--what the function does, and what it returns, as a single sentence. Count throwing uncaught errors as a return value for docstring purposes.
- Don't use the backslash continuation in python when you can avoid it. Where you've used it, you can instead use parentheses, or three assert statements.
- Your program should probably print a full rules explanation for the player, let alone the reviewer.

Answer (score 0):

StackExchange's Q&A format doesn't lend itself well to discussions, so I'll just point out a few random things, instead:

- `gameBoard` should be `GameBoard`, by naming convention.
- I can't really tell what/why `item_id` is used for. (`self.outline * self.item_id`?)
- I think it'd be nicer to make code read more linearly by getting rid of some syntactical code nesting (`if > for`, `for > while`, `for > for`). (Can't change logical nesting ofc, but can reorganize to *aesthetically* remove nesting.) This is kinda related to "Don't mix different levels of abstraction".
- I would avoid having `GameBoard` inherit from `np.ndarray` b/c [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- You've got a lot of code that's like `xyz_1` and `xyz_2` (piece lists, boards, players, etc). Would feel more elegant as just `players[0]` and `players[1]` with `player.board`, etc.